# Overwrite google.map with location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a main javascript file which generates a google map inside a div. This div is under many others which contains graphically visible datas needs for... somethgin similar to a dashboard. But on several other subpages I want to dynamically reload the map with unique parameters, but I can't according to the main map is listened on the load event. Not used the google map v3 api so much times so could anyone help me?
The main is generated by:

```
function mapInitialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        styles: mapStyle
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapInitialize);
```

In one of my subpage I want to generate a map with specific center, coordinates and a unique marker. So what I basically would do is to cal lagain the whole initialize() with my specific attributes, but it generates itself firstly then the one in main.js overwrite this already generated and wrong one :( How could I manage this easily, according to there are several subpages which should show this kind of unique datas after the page is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maps allows you to recenter the map after a map is already initialized:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    title: markerTitle,
    map: map,
});

map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
```

Additionally, what keeps you from reinitializing the map whenever you want? Just because it is registered with an on load listener shouldn't prevent you from making new instances? (I think):

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);`

Comment: Thank you, but still the main map loads first, and just then loads the new map, it's my problem... to get rip of this double-loading :s